# Why doesn't this for loop execute?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, loops, uipickerview

I have a picker view controller to select a chemical source and possibly a concentration.  If the source doesn't have concentrations, it just presents a single picker.  It gets populated by an `NSDictionary` with source type names as `keys` and a custom model object I made called `Chemical` that has four properties, two `NSString`, one `float` and one `BOOL`.

When I trigger this with dictionary that has 2 components, I want to extract the four values from the `Chemical` that is represented.  Note that I populate the picker with values from the first two properties, but not the `float` or `BOOL`.  I run through the array for the key that's selected in the first component and check the string from the second component against the `chemConcentration` property from each of the `Chemical`s in the key/value array.  When the `chemConcentration` matches, I know I have the right `Chemical` and I can get its properties to send back.

Whew!

The problem is that even though I know I get to the for loop, it seems to get skipped.  The `NSLog` right before it prints, but the one inside doesn't.  `sourceConstant` and `sourceIsLiquid` stay `0.0` and `NO`

```
- (IBAction)selectedSourceButton {
    NSLog(@"selectedSourceButton pressed");
    NSInteger sourceRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kSourceComponent];
    NSString *selectedSource = [self.sources objectAtIndex:sourceRow];
    NSArray *selectedChemicalGroup = [dictionaryOfSources objectForKey:selectedSource];
    NSInteger concentrationRow = [picker selectedRowInComponent:kConcentrationComponent];
    NSString *selectedConcentration = [[NSString alloc] init];
    float selectedConstant = 0.0;
    BOOL selectedIsLiquid = NO;

    if (numberOfComponents == 2) {
        NSLog(@"numberOfComponents = 2 if/then chosen"); // <-- This prints.
        selectedConcentration = [self.concentrations objectAtIndex:concentrationRow];
        NSLog(@"begin selectedConcentration for loop.  Number of loops = %d", [selectedChemicalGroup count]); // <-- And so does this.
        for (int i; i<[selectedChemicalGroup count]; i++) { // <-- But this doesn't seem to fire!
            NSLog(@"selectedConcentration = %@, from selectedChemicalGroup = %@", selectedConcentration, [[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:i] chemConcentration]); // <-- Because this doesn't print.
            if ([selectedConcentration isEqualToString:[[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:i] chemConcentration]]) {
            selectedConstant = [[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:i] chemConstant];
            selectedIsLiquid = [[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:i] chemIsLiquid];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        selectedConcentration = @"";
        selectedConstant = [[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:0] chemConstant];
        selectedIsLiquid = [[selectedChemicalGroup objectAtIndex:0] chemIsLiquid];
    }
    NSLog(@"selectedSourceButton source to return = %@, concentration = %@, sourceConstant = %1.7f, isLiquid = %d", selectedSource, selectedConcentration, selectedConstant, selectedIsLiquid);
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector (sourcePickerViewController:didSelectSource:andConcentration:andConstant:andIsLiquid:)]) {
        [self.delegate sourcePickerViewController:self didSelectSource:selectedSource andConcentration:selectedConcentration andConstant:selectedConstant andIsLiquid:selectedIsLiquid];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Initialize loop count i

```
for (int i = 0; i<[selectedChemicalGroup count]; i++)
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to initialize your variable `i`: `for (int i = 0; ...`

But there's a better way to do this, using "fast enumeration":

```
for (MyChemicalGroupClass *group in selectedChemicalGroup) {
    if ([selectedConcentration isEqualToString:[group chemConcentration]]) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do the following and you will understand why:

```
int i;
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```